# nodejs - run grunt task programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, frontend, grunt-contrib-watch

i'm using grunt tasks to **watch** and **concatenate** some js files.

my first configuration worked fine:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      js: {
        files: ['web/**/*.js'], 
        tasks: ['concat:JS'] 
      }
    },
    concat: { 
      JS: {
        files: {
          "index.js": [
            "test-1.js",
            "test-2.js",
          ],
          "about_us.js": [
            "test-3.js",
            "test-4.js",
          ],
          "store.js": [
            "test-5.js",
            "test-6.js",
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

my problem is that with this configuration whenever i change a file it concatenates everything.

i would be able to **concatenate only a specific file** (based on which file changed).

e.g. if i change `test-1.js` i would like concatenate only the `index.js` file (..so the task to run should be `'concat:JS:index.js'` )

so i tryed adding a watch event

```
 grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
        var taskName = "concat:JS"; //here i calculate dinamically the specific task name to be run
        grunt.task.run(taskName);
    });
```

but nothing happens.. any idea? thanks

Comment: So what I've got so far: run is used to append task to the current execution queue, it's not gonna execute it until the current task has finished. 
I think this could help find the solution: [https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/docs/watch-examples.md#using-the-watch-event]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### New answer post edit to question

Using the `grunt.event.on('watch', ...)` listener is the wrong tool for this kind of requirement. Instead you should utilize multiple [Targets](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) for both the the `watch` and `concat` tasks as shown in the `Gruntfile.js` excerpt below.

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
grunt.initConfig({
  watch: {
    'JS-index': {
      files: ['web/js/test-1.js', 'web/js/test-2.js'], 
      tasks: ['concat:JS-index']
    },
    'JS-about-us': {
      files: ['web/js/test-3.js', 'web/js/test-4.js'], 
      tasks: ['concat:JS-about-us']
    },
    'JS-store': {
      files: ['web/js/test-5.js', 'web/js/test-6.js'], 
      tasks: ['concat:JS-store']
    }
  },
  concat: { 
    'JS-index': {
      files: {
        'dist/js/index.js': [
          "web/js/test-1.js",
          "web/js/test-2.js",
        ]
      }
    },
    'JS-about-us': {
      files: {
        "dist/js/about_us.js": [
          "web/js/test-3.js",
          "web/js/test-4.js",
        ]
      }
    },
    'JS-store': {
      files: {
        'dist/js/store.js': [
          "web/js/test-5.js",
          "web/js/test-6.js",
        ]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**Notes**

Given the configuration shown above, the following will happen after running `grunt watch` via your CLI:

1. Changing either `test-1.js` or `test-2.js` will concatenate both files to `dist/js/index.js`.
2. Changing either `test-3.js` or `test-4.js` will concatenate both files to `dist/js/about_us.js`.
3. Changing either `test-5.js` or `test-6.js` will concatenate both files to `dist/js/store.js`.

*Your paths will need to be configured as necessary*

---

#### Original answer before edit to question

> how do i execute a task with grunt?

Using [`grunt.task.run`](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.run) is the correct way to programmatically run a task.

However, see this [comment](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/65#issuecomment-15063567) in the `grunt-contrib-watch` github repo. Excerpts from it read:

> *"Don't use `grunt.event.on('watch')` to run your tasks."*

and...

> *"The watch event is not intended for running tasks."*

The following solution assumes your requirement is to concatenate some `.js` files when one of them is changed/edited. In which case you need to utilize the `tasks` property of the `watch` task to define which task to run (I.e. `'concat:JS'`)

---

**Gruntfile**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      js: {
        files: ['path/to/js/**/*.js'], // <-- 1. Glob pattern to .js files
        tasks: ['concat:JS'] // <-- 2. Task to run when .js file changes.
      }
    },
    concat: {  // <-- 3. Configure your `concat` task as necessary.
      JS: {
        src: [
          'path/to/js/foo.js',
          'path/to/js/bar.js',
          'path/to/js/quux.js'
        ],
        dest: 'path/to/output/combined.js'
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

  grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
    console.log("yep, this code is being executed");
    // 4. <-- Do not run task from 'on' listener event.
  });
}
```

---

**Notes**

1. In your `watch` task define the glob pattern to the source `.js` files to watch for changes.
2. Specify the task to run when a `.js` file changes; I.e. `'concat:JS'`
3. Configure your `concat` task as necessary.
4. Remove `grunt.task.run('concat:JS');` from the `grunt.event.on('watch', ...)` listener.
5. Using the gist above and running `grunt` via your cli creates a new `combined.js` file when any change is made to a `.js` file stored in the `path/to/js/` directory. *(You'll need to configure the paths as per your requirements)*
6. Whilst the `grunt.event.on('watch', ...)` listener should not be used to run a task, it can be utilized to configure other tasks.